# How to combine 3 models in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I would like to create 3 models that have a relationship with each other and that do not cause collisions in the database.

I would like to create a user, restaurant and menu item model.

The User model can have a list of restaurants in relationship one to many - one user can own many restaurants.

A `Restaurant` model can have a list of menu items in a one to many relationship - one restaurant can have multiple menu items. In addition, I would like the user to be able to delete restaurants with the entire menu and also to be able to delete individual menu items from the restaurant.

My question is how to combine these relationships in `OnModelCreating` and which `DeleteBehaviour` to use so that the database does not crash after migration and update-database? I did some coding but I'm not sure if it is correct.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public List<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Restaurant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public List<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; } = new List<MenuItem>();
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
    public Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Restaurants)
        .WithOne(r => r.User)
        .HasForeignKey(r => r.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Restaurant>()
        .HasMany(r => r.MenuItems)
        .WithOne(mi => mi.Restaurant)
        .HasForeignKey(mi => mi.RestaurantId);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear. What do you mean crash? What error do you see?

Comment: You don't need to specify the relations at all, at least in EF Core, if the types and properties follow naming conventions. As far as I can tell, these classes do, so there's no need for extra code in `OnModelCreating`

Comment: `delete restaurants with the entire menu` that's a cascading operation, not a relation. In EF Core 6+ (I think) cascade delete will be used by default, because the non-nullable properties are considered required. [Required relations are configured to use cascade delete by default in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete)